# Prevent line break in this case

Tags: html, css, whitespace, nowrap

I am trying to prevent line breaking in this Html

http://jsfiddle.net/DD3v8/

It happens that when I resize my window, both icons and text break into new line. I've already tried with whitespace CSS property. I've tried also, a table approach, but the behaviour is the same

Can anyone figure what is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have your try to use nowrap tag/attribute?

Comment: @Dmitry You mean whitespace: nowrap property? Yes, I did

Comment: No, I meant nowrap tag: <npwrap>Some text</nowrap>

Comment: Please add the code from jsfiddle.net here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
.line {
            height: 44px; 
            width: 100%; 
            display: inline-block; 
            background-color: #6c7987;
            white-space: nowrap;
            position: relative;
        }

        .icon {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            height: 44px; 
            width: 90px; 
            background-color: 
            #FF0080; 
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 44px;
            font-family: Arial;
            float: left;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .title {
            position: absolute;
            left: 90px;
            color: white;
            line-height: 44px;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 0 0 0 10px;
            font-family: Arial;
            float: left;
            font-size: 12px;
            display: inline;
            white-space:nowrap;
        }

        .botoes {

            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            right: 0
        }

        .botao {
            width: 46px;
            height: 45px;
            float: right;
            line-height: 44px;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            white-space:nowrap;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .botaoVerRecurso {
            background: url('http://www.think-cell.com/images/cross.png') center no-repeat;
        }

        .botaoVerRecurso:hover {
            background: url('http://www.think-cell.com/images/cross.png') center no-repeat;
        }

        .botaoEditarRecurso {
            background: url('http://www.think-cell.com/images/cross.png') center no-repeat;
        }

        .botaoEditarRecurso:hover {
            background: url('http://www.think-cell.com/images/cross.png') center no-repeat;
        }

        .botaoFavRecurso {
            background: url('http://www.think-cell.com/images/cross.png') center no-repeat;
        }

        .botaoFavRecurso:hover {
            background: url('http://www.think-cell.com/images/cross.png') center no-repeat;
        }

        .botaoPartRecurso {
            background: url('http://www.think-cell.com/images/cross.png') center no-repeat;
        }

        .botaoPartRecurso:hover {
            background: url('http://www.think-cell.com/images/cross.png') center no-repeat;
        }

        .botaoApagarRecurso {
            background: url('http://www.think-cell.com/images/cross.png') center no-repeat;
        }

        .botaoApagarRecurso:hover {
            background: url('http://www.think-cell.com/images/cross.png') center no-repeat;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }
```

​

The explanation is simple: with floating, you can't put more width to a holder, which is bigger than the holder's height, the float will automatically drops it, and breaks line.

If you use positions, use it like this:

CONTAINER (position: relative)
   SUBelement (posision: absolute, top: 0, left: 0) < put to the top left
   SUBelement (posision: absolute, bottom: 0, right: 0) < put to the bottom right

in W3C: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Careful though, w3schools isn't related by any kind to W3C. Read more http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correcly, you need to be able to resize the window width without having the text and the "x" icons jumping down, is so:

**REMOVE CSS FROM `.title`**

```
min-width: 500px;
```

See this [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/DD3v8/3/)!