# On browser re size the div comes down

Tags: html, css, css-float

In the header I have given four differents and used the float property tomake everything display in a horizontal line.

When I resize the browser window, the last div comes down below the black border line.

How to fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/m6uBA/

```
<div class="mainDiv" style="border-bottom: 1px solid grey; height: 80px;">
            <div class="subDiv" style="font-size: 24px; color: grey; padding-left: 35px;">
                Company LOGO
            </div>
            <div class="subDiv" style="padding-left: 50px;">
                <p><span style="font-weight: bold;  font-family: arial; color: #333;">welcome xyz!</span> xyz@defie.co</p>
            </div>
            <div class="subDivMenu" style="width: 911px; margin-top: 0px; padding-left: 17px; ">


                <div class="inline" style="padding-top: 12px; ">

                    <ul class="homePageLists" style="">
                                    <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #333;">
                                      <a style="color: #cc0000; font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                         Menu
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #; ">
                                      <a style="color: #666; font-weight: bold;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                        <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">
                                        Inventory
                                      </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #653921; ">
                                      <a style="color: #666; font-weight: bold;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                        <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_vender.png">
                                        Vendors
                                      </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #653921; ">
                                      <a style="color: #666; font-weight: bold;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                          <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_vender.png">
                                          Quote
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #9e1c20; ">
                                      <a style="color: #666; font-weight: bold;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                          <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_vender.png">
                                          Purchase Orders
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #ff5100; ">
                                      <a style="color: #666; font-weight: bold;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                        <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_vender.png">
                                        Invoices
                                      </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #184179;">
                                      <a style="color: #666; font-weight: bold;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                          <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_vender.png">
                                          RMA
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #184179;">
                                      <a style="color: #666; font-weight: bold;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                          <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_vender.png">
                                          Account Receivable
                                      </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

            </div>
            <div class="subDiv" style="float: right;">

                  <p style="font-weight: bold;">ABC Systems</p>
                  <p>1234 lakeview Blvd, CA 94538</p>
                  <p>510-657-8981</p>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This has been answered before.

check this old thread: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704630/prevent-line-break-in-this-case>

Comment: @henser: can you update in the fiddle its confusing

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new class to .subDiv e.g .welcome and floating it right rather then using float left on both elements in your header.

Answer (score 0):

how about this.

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/rosario10/m6uBA/31/

Comment: thanks for your reply...i wanted all the div to be above black line